# Grant select to dbo view without select on non dbo tables

Tags: sql-server, security, schema, view

SQL Server 2008 R2

We have a login & user called "JoeBlogs", this user has it's own default `schema` of JoeBlogs - it has `Public` access only to the database.

We then granted it `SELECT` on a `dbo` view - the `dbo` view however selects data from underlying tables that belong to a **non-dbo** schema - so we get an error selecting from the view saying access was denied to underlying tables.

How does one configure the user to have select access to the `dbo` view but **not** the underlying **non-dbo** tables?

Is this even possible?

Jordon

Comment: Hi, as stated in the question we have already granted SELECT on the view to the user, i've granted view definition too - no change, still get access denied on the underlying tables.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic751807-359-1.aspx#bm1276920)? See if you're missing an AUTHORIZATION clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to understand the problem before proceeding with the solution.
When you select from a view the SQL Server system would check permissions twice:
Once when you select from the view, and once when the view makes reference to the underlying table.
Obviously the second check would fail if the user has no permission on the underlying table.

Microsoft have solved this with "Ownership Chaining" (known as OC).
OC will bypass the permission check that would be done when the view is referencing the table,
**Only** if the owner of the view is the same as the owner of the table.
The thing is, OC is bypassing permission checks completely, which means that it can bypass denies as well...
For example, if "JoeBlogs" has the `create view` permission, he can create a new view which has access to the entire table.
I suggest you read about ownership chaining before you decide your course of action.

[books online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms188676%28v=sql.105%29)
[msdn blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20160226235658/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/lcris/archive/2007/09/13/basic-sql-server-security-concepts-ownership-chaining-good-and-evil-schemas.aspx)
[detailed example, using a stored procedure instead of view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb153640(v=sql.105).aspx)

Having said that, the first Intuitive solution would be to create the view under the same **non-dbo** schema as the underlying tables (or a schema owned by the same user as the **non-dbo** schema).
However, if you find that solution to be too risky there is another (and maybe even better) option:
You can always use a  function (Multistatement Table-valued Function) with an `EXECUTE AS` clause:
[Create function syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755(v=sql.105).aspx)
[execute as clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188354(v=sql.105).aspx)
This method will allow you to select from the function (`execute` permission on the function) while the function belongs to `dbo`. The user specified in the `execute as` clause must have permissions on the underlying tables.