# SQL Server - How to grant SELECT permission on View that access data in schemas from differents owners?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need help to deal with a problem about permissions in my database.

This is the scenario:

**1 Database**

**4 Schemas**:

- **schemaA**; owner **dbo**
- **schemaB**; owner **ownerX**
- **schemaC**; owner **ownerX**
- **schemaD**; owner **ownerX**

In **schemaD** I have a view named **viewABC**, that gets information from tables and views allocated on schemas **schemaA**, **schemaB** e **schemaC**.

A user **userX** have `SELECT` permission for **viewABC**.

With the following command I grant permission:

```
GRANT SELECT ON schemaD.viewABC TO userX;
```

When **userX** try to execute a `SELECT` against the view, this way:

```
SELECT * FROM schemaD.viewABC;
```

We get the error:

> The SELECT permission was denied on object 'tableA', database
>   'MyDatabase', schema 'schemaA'.

I do understand that the error happens because **tableA** is on a **different schema, with a different owner (dbo instead ownerX)**, and SQLServer applies userX **permissions to grant or deny access**. Once **userX don´t have explicit access to tableA** the query execution returns error.

How to solve this **without grant SELECT permission on tableA for userX**?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on one of the suggestions that Dan Guzman gave me in your answer, and after read this [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27229/grant-select-to-dbo-view-without-select-on-non-dbo-tables?rq=1) I found a **workaround** to my problem.

Apparently, there is no way, in scenario as described, to grant to **userX** `SELECT` permission in the **viewABC without grant also SELECT permission on tableA**.

The solution that I found was the following:

- in **schemaD** I created a [Table-Valued Function](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165.aspx) that return the same record set of **viewABC** - despite **ownerX** isn't owner of **schemaA**, he has `SELECT` permission on **tableA**
- the `EXECUTE AS` [clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188354(v=sql.105).aspx) was used to guarantee that any execution of the function will use **ownerX permissions** - in this context doesn't matter the permission that **userX has on tableA**
- to **userX** was granted `SELECT` **permission in the created function** - not `EXECUTE` permission, since the **function return a table**

---

The **Table-Valued Function** sample code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION schemaD.udfABC ()
RETURNS @tabABC TABLE (
  fieldA INT NOT NULL, fieldB INT NOT NULL, fieldC INT NOT NULL
)
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO @tabABC (fieldA, fieldB, fieldC)
    SELECT a.fieldA, b.fieldB, c.fieldC
      FROM schemaA.tableA a
     INNER JOIN schemaB.tableB b ON a.id = b.idA
     INNER JOIN schemaC.tableC c ON b.id = c.idB;

  RETURN;  
END
```

Granting `SELECT` permission:

```
GRANT SELECT ON schemaD.udfABC TO userX;
```

Now **userX** can use this command to get data:

```
SELECT * FROM schemaD.udfABC();
```

Comment: What is the performance of select from `Table Valued Function` vs select from `View`? Is it the same? I mean large tables.

Comment: In my case I didn't had significant performance issues, but i tested only in tables with few records (10,000 records or less...)

Comment: This is just fundamentally broken! The ability for a table owner to create a view and give other users SELECT access to the view without access to the underlying table is simply basic to SQL databases. I've worked with DB2, Oracle, PostGre, and MySQL and all of them work that way. I can't imagine the table valued function being a problem for performance, but still...

Comment: Oh, fhs! `WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER` _'(except inline table-valued functions)'_. I had wondered why you had the awful `@tabABC` logic...

Answer (score 4):

I can't think of a way to avoid granting `SELECT` permissions due to the broken ownership chain in the view's underlying objects.  One solution is to change the owner of TableA to ownerX so that the view ownership chain is unbroken:

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON OBJECT::dbo.tableA TO ownerX;
```

Note that this will give ownerX `CONTROL` permissions on dbo.tableA.  If that is not acceptable, you'll need to use a module instead (e.g. table-valued function) and sign it with a certificate based on a user that has the needed object `SELECT` permissions.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the owner of tableA. Anyway thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I'll try to make a table-valued function with a EXECUTE AS clause.